# Create an editor or tab for addon

Tags: python, add-on

the way I understand it the most popular way to create an addon is to make it a panel.

Is there any way to create an addon that would look like Properties Editor or at least make a new tab in the Properties Editor that would house addon functionality?

I came across this post but couldn't get it to work:
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/developing-a-new-editor/894

[image]

Comment: Short answer is with python, no (unless it's a custom *node* editor), and no

Comment: (@Gorgious the devtalk thread discusses how to do this in a mix of C++ plus Python but it's not clear that that anyone has ever accomplished it.)  At any rate, nobody here is prepared to help you debug the C++ code for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! 
@MartyFouts I completely understand. I myself am not prepared to dig into C++ to make this happen. 
I just thought that maybe I missed something so this is a huge time saver for me. Thanks again.